# How may I use this C loop to solve that integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Let C be the curve of polar equation $r = 2cos^2(\theta)$ and D the area bounded by the loop C which is situated in the half-plane $x \ge 0$ region.

How may I calculate the D's area and use it to evaluate:

\begin{equation*}
\int\int_{R} x^{11}y^{20} dA,
\end{equation*}

where R is the region of the plane bounded by the curve C?
Does C has a easy Cartesian equation in polynomial form??

As I'm stuck, so any tip will be helpful

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The region looks like this. Because $x\ge0$, we get that $-\pi/2\le\theta\le\pi/2$.
For full credit calculate enough many points on it so that you can explain why the region has approximately this shape.

[image]

To calculate the integral in polar coordinates you thus need to remember that

1. $0\le r\le 2\cos^2\theta$,
2. $-\pi/2\le\theta\le\pi/2$,
3. $x=r\cos\theta$,
4. $y=r\sin\theta$,
5. $dA=r\,dr\,d\theta$.

I would use either a table of integrals or a CAS (or Wolfram Alpha) to calculate the resulting $\theta$-integral. The standard technique would also take me to the finish line, but I am feeling lazy and leaving that to you. The tables usually give trigonometric integrals over the interval $[0,\pi/2]$. As the exponent of $y$ is even, and $\cos^2\theta$ is also an even function we have a $(x,y)\leftrightarrow (x,-y)$ -symmetry, and may as well calculate the integral over $[0,\pi/2]$ and then multiply the result by two.

If you want to write this equation in cartesian coordinates, then first multiply it by $r^2$ to get
$$
r^3=2r^2\cos^2\theta=2(r\cos\theta)^2.
$$
Then observe that $r\cos\theta=x$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This gives you
$$
(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}=2x^2.
$$
I'm not sure how useful that is :-) You can make it polynomial by squaring it.